# D3DXSprite and showing textures and rotating them in different ways

Tags: directx, 2d

i have many textures to show on the screen, some of these textures may have rotation or other transformation. All transformation independent. Do i need to create D3DXSprite for every independent texture? Because, if i create only one sprite and apply transformation it have an affect for every texture in the sprite. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as the documentation to ID3DXSprite::Draw() states:

To scale, rotate, or translate a sprite, call ID3DXSprite::SetTransform with a matrix that contains the scale, rotate, and translate (SRT) values, before calling ID3DXSprite::Draw. For information about setting SRT values in a matrix, see Matrix Transforms.

So it would look something like this:

```
d3dxSpriteObject.Begin([...]);
for(int i=0; i<numTextures; i++) 
{
    d3dxSpriteObject.SetTransform(matrix);
    d3dxSpriteObject.Draw(texture[i], NULL, textureCenter[i], texturePos[i], 0xffffffff);
}
d3dxSpriteObject.End();
```

Comment: if some object will not get transformation, do i need to do next SetTransformation or may be better way    >D3DXMATRIX matrix;
D3DXMatrixScaling(&matrix, 1, 1, 1);
gSprite->SetTransform(&matrix);

Comment: I can only guess, but my guess is that the transformation will stay the same as long until you call the next SetTransform(). So i guess with something like SetTransform(); Draw(); Draw(); _both_ draw-calls will be made with what you set on the SetTransform(). You should just try it out ;)